# MapReduce with Hadoop, "Ouput file directory already exists"

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to use a cluster hosted on Amazons EMR service. I'm trying to run the WordCount example using a WordCount.jar file, and input1.txt with a random output folder. My syntax for the input is, WordCount argv[1] argv[2]. The path for input1.txt would be argv[1], and argv[2] is the path to the output. I'm aware that hadoop gets mad if you try to use the same output directory multiple times. Just to be absolutely sure for you guys, I have the lines ->

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));
```

Yet no matter what output directory I put in this is my result,

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mydirectory/gabagooba already exists
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:146)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:268)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:141)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1341)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1338)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1844)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1338)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1359)
at WordCountDemo.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:239)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153)
```

My output directories are meant to be stored in S3 storage, but when I go there, there is no outputs present. Any help would get me out of this rut.

Comment: Please show the commands you're running and the error for each

Answer (score 1):

Can you specify the output location as s3
instead of https.

Example: s3://yourbucket/output

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-output.html